# Amazon EC2 - Provides a dedicated IP?

Tags: ip, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm thinking of using Elastic Beanstalk (which uses EC2).

Will I receive a dedicated IP address?

Is an Elastic IP a dedicated IP?

I do not want to share an IP with other people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a shared IP, it's a 'personal' IP. You are the only one that has access to it.

Comment: Are my servers the only ones using the IP address? (which is what dedicated offers)

Comment: Yes they are the only ones.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you talking about the Elastic IPs, or non-Elastic?

Comment: Do note that the IP could have been used by someone else, and it's possible they used it for nefarious purposes (and is thus listed in RBLs, though delisting shouldn't be hard these days)

Comment: I hereby, faithfully confirm with 100% assurance, pledging that this is true and that lightning may strike if it is not so. Scouts Honor!

Comment: +1 (I wish) to @Chris S. I never thought of that. But chances of receiving a blacklisted IP are slim...

Comment: Well, if the concept of a "previously-owned" IP bothers you, you could check into running IPv6.....